# babel transpile to es5 doesnt work for node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel-loader

I am trying to run my current project in ie11, but it gives me an error saying `SCRIPT1002: syntax error` in foundation.js (its part of google's material design classes). The line in question is `export default MDCFoundation`. Now from what i have red the issue is that this is es6 code and ie11 only supports es5. So far so good. The problem now is I cant seem to figure out how to tell babel to transpile to es5. I am using webpack and babel, here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry:{
    app: ['./src/app.js']
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  externals: /^(tables.)/i,
  module: {
    rules: 
    [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // <---- added here
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
            }
          }
         ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // <--- added here
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
            },
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: /src/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          "presets": [
            ["env", {
              "targets": {
                "browsers": ["ie >= 11"]
              }
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: 'style.css'}),
    new LiveReloadPlugin({}),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', jquery: 'jquery' })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js']
  },

  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: './dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  }
};
```

As you can see I am already trying to tell babel to transpile for ie11, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: What's the content of `foundation.js`? You configured your `babel-loader` to ONLY transpile files from `src` directory so make sure you are not using anything outside of `src`. Also, what `webpack` and `babel` versions are you using?

Comment: @PavelDenisjuk Ohhh wow, now I feel kind of stupid. I added node_modules to the include list of babel and now it works (the tabs still dont work, but at least its not giving me any error.). 
For completeness sake: you can view the content of `foundation.js` [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/packages/mdc-base/foundation.js). I am using version 4.15.1 of webpack and 7.1.5 of babel-loader.

Comment: Right, so it is Material's source code which is located in `node_modules` (it wasn't clear from the original question). Well now you know what was wrong, good luck! Also: do NOT add the entire `node_modules` folder to babel-loader, only add that single package, as 99% of the packages coming from `npm` are already ES5.